# Worm fanfic where Taylor is at a school dance with the Wards when Skidmark attacks

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, worm

I'm pretty sure that it's an alternate power fanfic, although I don't recall what power Taylor has (I want to say it's something involving metal, maybe magnetic powers?). She's at a school dance for Arcadia, with several Wards in attendance (I think she runs into a few in their civilian identities without realizing they're Wards, which makes me think she might be dating one of them as a civilian and hadn't been brought behind the mask). Skidmark, not knowing identities, but working off of the common knowledge that some of the Wards go to Arcadia, decides to target the dance, with him setting up an acceleration field at one side of the hall and having Mush unload debris onto the field, resulting in multiple injuries. I remember Taylor taking cover behind a table, I think after dragging a wounded student (possibly Dennis), and finding a way to use her power to turn the tables, but not until after people had been injured.

I'm pretty sure this was an isolated scene, albeit one which had plot consequences, if nothing else putting a spotlight on Taylor for her unexpected heroic actions. I don't remember when I read this, but I think it was at least five years ago, when I was on more of a kick of reading random *Worm* fanfic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, in the process of looking names up, I had a set of search terms run through my head. `worm fanfic skidmark "school dance"` (I previously overcomplicated it with key words involving "shrapnel" and "debris") turned up "[Railgun](https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/railgun-worm-a-certain-scientific-railgun.291891/)", which is indeed an alt-power!Taylor fanfic where she gains electromagnetic powers (apparently the powerset of the main character of *[A Certain Scientific Railgun](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/ACertainScientificRailgun)*).

[Chapter 2.03](https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/railgun-worm-a-certain-scientific-railgun.291891/page-9#post-20847207) is the one where Skidmark shows up.

> Screams rang out around me, as debris hurled itself into the room. I rose to my feet and immediately saw the source of the fast moving objects.
>
> Skidmark had painted the area in front of the double doors of the gymnasium with his power. How many layers, I had no idea. But it was enough that when the members of his gang began throwing things into the room, they were accelerated to more than ten times their earlier velocity.
>
> Worse, the things that they were throwing weren't anything I would have expected. Instead of bullets or bombs, they were throwing some of the most disgusting things I had ever seen. The reek of human feces exploded into the room as a gang member emptied a five gallon bucket of what could only be actual shit onto the barrier, the material exploding across the room to impact the far wall, as well as everyone and everything in between.

....

> Even as I watched, I saw what had just happened repeat itself. Over the blue bands that Skidmark had laid down, I saw Mush push out his arms, allowing the glow there to strip the material from them and hurl it forward into the gym and the defenseless students there.
>
> Worse, while Mush usually used ordinary trash to create his outer form, this time, he'd apparently used a lot of broken glass and shattered bricks. So the debris shooting out from his form was razor sharp, jagged and hard, moving at well over two hundred miles an hour.